# How to find and replace a zero but not a 0 in 1000 (using exact match find and replace) - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a sheet with a mix of numbers. I want to replace all zeros with "100+" but not the zeros in larger numbers, for example 1000. Using the normal find and replace would turn the 1000 into 1100+100+100+ which is wrong. I basically just need it to replace all zeros and nothing else.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would help your explanation to show sample inputs and required outputs.

Comment: Do you actually want to replace the numbers, or just format them to look that way?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at SuperUser instead?

Comment: I have around 500 columns with numbers ranging from 0 to 500. A low number e.g 1 is good with the exception of 0. So I want to find the best score for each column. If I just use =Min it will return 0 which is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

When using Find and Replace, click Options and then check Match the entire cell content.

Comment: its not on excel which is on mac